# Render tag to Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I want to render a tag with link to a jade file, but it shows me the code text, not the link.

I have tried pipe but it doesn't work either with or without the pipe.

contents.jade

```
div
  p 
   |#{DUL}
```

contents.js

```
var DUL = `a(href='/contents/delete_process') delete`
response.render('contents', DUL: DUL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render html markup in pug you have to interpolate it with an exclamation mark !{var} like this:

```
div
  p 
   |!{DUL}
```

And change the value from DUL to

`var DUL = '<a href="/contents/delete_process">delete</a>';`